# Assistance installing libbitcoin

Tags: python, macos, module, installation, bitcoin

I know that this might be a stupid question and this might also be the wrong place to ask it. I was wondering, basically, how to install libbitcoin on Mac OSX *(Lion)*. Before I get a lot of grief about how I haven't posted any code etc. I'll have you know that I have tried `easy_install` and `pip` *(the only methods I know)*. I have researched my problem but have found no answers. This seems to be the best place to ask this question.

Comment: `libbitcoin` [isn't in the PyPI listings](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=bitcoin&submit=search) that `easy_install` and `pip` use; it's set up to be installed as a library on its own, not as a python package. The source seems to be at https://gitorious.org/libbitcoin/libbitcoin. But when I cloned and tried to install, `autoreconf` failed (`archiver requires 'AM_PROG_AR' in 'configure.ac'`), and there seems to be no other documentation about the install process (though there is an Ubuntu package).